# How to solve flutter video player bad quality

Tags: video, flutter, media-player, video-player, software-quality

I'm developing this media player app with flutter, I've followed the instructions on the flutter video player plugin documentation on the flutter official Dev site.
I noticed that whatever video that gets played in the app loses a lot of quality, having what appears to be lines on the playing video which will be bad for market.
Anyone done something like this before? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should use [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) 
The video player for Flutter with a heart of gold.

In your pubspec.yaml file within your Flutter Project:

dependencies:

```
  chewie: <latest_version>
  video_player: <latest_version>
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: From the documentation of the chewie player, it uses most of the code in the video_player plugin. I'd try it though.

Comment: So can you add the full code of how you implemented so that I can have a look.

Comment: I just did that. I used the latest chewie version and it's still having the same problem. I think it has something to do with how Flutter renders its UI. I'm currently far from my PC, but I didn't do anything hideous. In fact, I copied the code from the chewie example code in the documentation.

Comment: I don't hinks thats a problem because flutter rendering. It could be the problem of your video file or the extension of the video file, also it could be the problem with the emulator.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? Does the video play with as much quality as with some other media player app? I run the app on a real device and play the same video in some other media player like VLC to compare.

Comment: that's why I am asking for the code so that I could implement on my system

Comment: I'm facing same issue with a locale video.

I downloaded one in a tablet. If i open it with the  device's default video player, then i got a better quality compared of the flutter video_player plugin...